# How to make a discord bot to create a invite in other guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't get the bot to make a invite on another guild the bot is in.

I've tried giving my bot the adminstrator role to make sure it has permissions.

```
if(msg.content.startsWith('-createinvite')) {
    const args = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1)
    if(!args[0])
        var invitechannels = guild.channels.filter(c => c.members.get(bot.user.id).hasPermission("CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE")).first();
    var guild = client.guilds.get(args[0]);
    if (!guild) return msg.reply("The bot isn't in the guild with this ID.");
    if(!invitechannels) return msg.channel.send('No Channels found with permissions to create Invite in!')
    console.log(invitechannels)
    invitechannels.random().createInvite().then(invite=> msg.channel.send('Found Invite:\n' + invite.code))
}
```

I've tried different kind of codes but I can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(msg.content.startsWith('-createinvite')) {
const args = msg.content.split(' ').slice(1)
let guild = client.guilds.get(args[0]);

if (!guild) return message.reply("The bot isn't in the guild with this ID.");

let invitechannels = guild.channels.filter(c=> c.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'))
if(!invitechannels) return message.channel.send('No Channels found with permissions to create Invite in!')

invitechannels.random().createInvite()
  .then(invite=> message.channel.send('Found Invite:\n' + invite.code))
}
```

You were verifying if the bot has permissions for a guild before getting the guild.
And this is not a thing `c.members.get(bot.user.id).hasPermission("CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE")).first()`